# Where does cPanel store websites?

Tags: virtualization, host

When I was using Plesk it was simply under /var/www, however it is empty when I have at least 2 sites now on a cPanel machine. What is cPanel's architecture in terms of storing files?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a plain vanilla install on a Centos server, then cPanel accounts are created under /home

The actual website root will be under:  /home/*accountname*/public_html
and a helpful link: /home/*accountname*/www

Edit: thanks for that hint re not using angle brackets in these comments

Comment: I think you must have put *username* in angle brackets and it was stripped out. try `*username*` instead of `<username>`

Answer (score 1):

The path is usually `/home/USERNAME` for a user's cPanel-related files. The `public-html` directory is where web files actually sit (i.e. http://example.org/index.html would be pulled from `/home/example/public_html/index.html` assuming the cPanel username would be `example` and that the user would be hosting example.org on his occount).